# React useMemo firing when no change to Redux state detected

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a state object in Redux and am using useSelector and deepEqual (from fast-deep-equal) to detect changes. Then useMemo on the current state. What's puzzling is that useMemo is being invoked even though the state seemingly hasn't changed.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
import deepEqual from "fast-deep-equal"

export function useMyState() {
    const values = useSelector(
        (store) => store.prop1,
        (a, b) => { // comparison function arg to useSelector
            const equal = deepEqual(a, b)
            if (!equal) {
                console.log("COMPARE FALSE")
            }
            return equal
        }
    )
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("MOUNTED")
    }, [])

    return useMemo(() => {
        console.log("VALUES CHANGED", JSON.stringify(values))
        return {
            values,
            method1() {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }, [values])
}
```

I confirm that `MOUNTED` is only output once, and that `VALUES CHANGED` is output even when `COMPARE FALSE` is NOT output. How can this be...?

Maybe if component happens to be rendered as part of parent render it always gets the current object from store (which is not `===` the previous value) and `useSelector` compare fn is only used to prevent re-render of the component (in isolation) when state has not changed? If this is the case, what is the best-practice way to prevent `useMemo` being run when values are deep-equal?

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-state-change-zdxzs

The issue occurs when there are two `useSelector` and one is triggered, causing a re-render. The component then thinks the result of the other `useSelector` has changed even though it has not according to the test in the selector itself (`deepEqual`).

To reproduce follow above link, click the increment button a few times - component is rendered but no change to todo items. Then click "re-create" button and increment again. Even though items have not changed according to `deepEqual` the text `TODOS CHANGED!` is output.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know `useSelector` will re-render if the state result is different from the previous state result from the store. But it doesn't look like you're calling a store state?

Comment: Have edited the code to make it clearer that prop1 is a property of the store object

Comment: Hey @jugglingcats so I took a look at your code. In your app store for the re-create button you're copying the state and replace it with `state` i.e. `refresh: (state) => [...state]`. The items may be unchanged, but as per the documentation for the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#copy_an_array), this actually copies the array into a new array and this should cause a re-render.